# PHP Multiselect with Chosen jQuery - Returning all values not just selected

Tags: php, jquery, forms, multi-select, jquery-chosen

I'm using a multiselect to get some values. This multiselect is using Chosen jQuery plugin.

For some reason in PHP this multiselect is returning all the values, not just the selected ones.

**The HTML**

```
<select name="taglist[]" size="10" id="taglist" style="width:350px;" class="chzn-select" multiple multiple-data-placeholder="Select some tags" >
**This is populated by Ajax**
</select>
```

**After Ajax population**

```
<option value="Student community of reflection - A conscious environment of cooperative sharing of ideas and proces">Student community of reflection - A conscious environment of cooperative sharing of ideas and proces</option>
<option value="Teacher inclusive conversations - Emphasis on a sharing of power with students; visibility that enco">Teacher inclusive conversations - Emphasis on a sharing of power with students; visibility that enco</option>
<option value="Teacher feedback - Awareness of the power of written, oral and symbolic feedback on students self co">Teacher feedback - Awareness of the power of written, oral and symbolic feedback on students self co</option>
<option value="Student self assessment ( metacognitive reflection) - Continuous opportunities for students to thin">Student self assessment ( metacognitive reflection) - Continuous opportunities for students to thin</option>
```

**The PHP**

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['taglist'] as $value)
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO recent_tags (t_name, t_owner, t_post) VALUES ('$value', '$uid',  '$id')") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

**The Result**

Array ( [0] => Student community of reflection - A conscious environment of cooperative sharing of ideas and proces [1] => Teacher inclusive conversations - Emphasis on a sharing of power with students; visibility that enco [2] => Teacher feedback - Awareness of the power of written, oral and symbolic feedback on students self co [3] => Student self assessment ( metacognitive reflection) - Continuous opportunities for students to thin )

**This is happening even though only 1 of these options was selected in the multiselect box**

Hope somebody will be able to help with this, its doing my head in.

**Result of print_r($_POST)**

```
Array ( [entry_name] => aaa [entry_content] => [tag_category] => Insider Classroom Framework [taglist] => Array ( [0] => Student community of reflection - A conscious environment of cooperative sharing of ideas and proces [1] => Teacher inclusive conversations - Emphasis on a sharing of power with students; visibility that enco [2] => Teacher feedback - Awareness of the power of written, oral and symbolic feedback on students self co [3] => Student self assessment ( metacognitive reflection) - Continuous opportunities for students to thin ) [button] => Post )
```

**Form post**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" onSubmit="return checkAll();" action="process/webpl_journal_entry_process.php">
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is in the select box after the AJAX request?

Comment: Added the ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your HTML is off. You have:

```
<select name="taglist[]" size="10" id="taglist" style="width:350px;" class="chzn-select" multiple multiple-data-placeholder="Select some tags" >
**This is populated by Ajax**
</select>
```

And I can't see how your 'inner-check-boxes' look, but I am almost certain that you don't have them as `name='taglist[]'`, where as you want them to carry that value, and you don't want your select `name` to be `taglist[]`.

If you are using a list, then you want to keep the select name as `taglist[]`, but don't want to name any inner-option, just have their `value`'s.

**EDIT:**
All code displayed, and works fine:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="taglist[]" size="10" id="taglist" style="width:350px;" class="chzn-select" multiple multiple-data-placeholder="Select some tags" >
<option value="Student community of reflection - A conscious environment of cooperative sharing of ideas and proces">Student community of reflection - A conscious environment of cooperative sharing of ideas and proces</option>
<option value="Teacher inclusive conversations - Emphasis on a sharing of power with students; visibility that enco">Teacher inclusive conversations - Emphasis on a sharing of power with students; visibility that enco</option>
<option value="Teacher feedback - Awareness of the power of written, oral and symbolic feedback on students self co">Teacher feedback - Awareness of the power of written, oral and symbolic feedback on students self co</option>
<option value="Student self assessment ( metacognitive reflection) - Continuous opportunities for students to thin">Student self assessment ( metacognitive reflection) - Continuous opportunities for students to thin</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if($_REQUEST['taglist']) {

    foreach ($_REQUEST['taglist'] as $value)
    {
        echo $value ."<br>\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Jon,What do you mean by 'inner-check-boxes'? I just added the results of the Ajax to my op.

Comment: Hi Jon, to clarify, I am using a multi-select list, none of the inner options have a name, only their values. Thanks!

Comment: With the added 'Ajax-populated' code, I just ran a small test with it, and there is nothing wrong with any of the code that you have displayed (other than the security hole of allowing straight html input into mysql).  Is `taglist` also defined elsewhere in the HTML, or redefined in the PHP?  What does a `print_r($_POST);` give? ^^  (also, how is the form submitted?)

Comment: Added the print_r output to the op.

Comment: How is the form submitted?  Posting a stand-a-lone page in my answer in one second that has all your code in it and works perfectly.

Comment: Im thinking it might be an issue with the Chosen jQuery plugin now.

`<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" onSubmit="return checkAll();" action="process/webpl_journal_entry_process.php">`

Comment: What does the function `checkAll()` look like? ^^

Comment: Oh man, I had a bit of legacy code in that Javascript function. All sorted now, thank you for your help!